# Word VBA: Update OLE Source Links

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, ole

I have about a dozen linked excel OLE objects in my word document.  These files get moved around the network frequently so I need an easy intuitive way for the underlying links to be updated.  I tried a code I found on this website however while it updated the source it seems to also update what is being shown in the object itself so all the objects change to whatever worksheet was in focus when the excel workbook was saved last.  I'm trying to retain format and range while updating the source. Any help would be great.

Here is the code I tried presently:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim OldFile As String
Dim xlsobj As Object
Dim xlsfile_chart As Object
Dim dlgSelectFile As FileDialog 'FileDialog object '
Dim thisField As Field
Dim selectedFile As Variant
'must be Variant to contain filepath of selected item
Dim newFile As Variant
Dim fieldCount As Integer '
Dim x As Long
On Error GoTo LinkError
'create FileDialog object as File Picker dialog box
Set dlgSelectFile = Application.FileDialog
(FileDialogType:=msoFileDialogFilePicker)

With dlgSelectFile
.Filters.Clear 'clear filters
.Filters.Add "Microsoft Excel Files", "*.xls, *.xlsb, *.xlsm,*.xlsx" 'filter 
for only Excel files

'use Show method to display File Picker dialog box and return user's action
If .Show = -1 Then
 'step through each string in the FileDialogSelectedItems collection
 For Each selectedFile In .SelectedItems
   newFile = selectedFile 'gets new filepath
 Next selectedFile
 Else 'user clicked cancel
 Exit Sub
 End If
 End With
 Set dlgSelectFile = Nothing
 'update fields



 Set xlsobj = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
 xlsobj.Application.Visible = False
 Set xlsfile_chart = xlsobj.Application.Workbooks.Open(newFile, ReadOnly = 
True)

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  With xlsobj.Application
 .calculation = xlcalculationmanual
 .enableevents = False
 End With



  fieldCount = ActiveDocument.Fields.Count
   For x = 1 To fieldCount
   With ActiveDocument.Fields(x)
   If .Type = 56 Then
  .LinkFormat.SourceFullName = newFile
    End If
   End With
  Next x

  With xlsobj.Application
 .calculation = xlcalculationmanual
 .enableevents = True
 End With

 Application.ScreenUpdating = True



  MsgBox "Data has been sucessfully linked to report"

   'clean up
    xlsfile_chart.Close SaveChanges:=False
   Set xlsfile_chart = Nothing
   xlsobj.Quit
   Set xlsobj = Nothing


    Exit Sub
LinkError:
  Select Case Err.Number
   Case 5391 'could not find associated Range Name
    MsgBox "Could not find the associated Excel Range Name " & _
   "for one or more links in this document. " & _
   "Please be sure that you have selected a valid " & _
   "Quote Submission input file.", vbCritical
    Case Else
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, vbCritical
   End Select


   ' clean up
    Set xlsfile_chart = Nothing
     xlsobj.Quit
     Set xlsobj = Nothing

    End Sub
```

Comment: Which version of Word? Exactly what commands were used to create these links? If you press Alt+F9 in Word to display the field codes, do you see any fields (LINK, probably) in place of the Excel data?

Comment: Excel & Word 2010. Yes, when pressing Alt+F9 there are field links.  An example as follows:

`{ LINK Excel.SheetMacroEnabled.12 "\\\\fp.usfed.org\\shared\\Business Services\\Internal\\FORMS & LETTERS\\Underwriting Template\\Test\\TEST2\\Analysis ToolSet for CP - Blank.xlsm" "Exposure Summary!R3C1:R22C12" \a \p }`